# Async Google analytics fake pageview tracking not working on links that lead outside the site

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm using jQuery to attach onClick events to certain elements on the site, depending on whether the element exists, example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( $("#webform-client-form-15897").length ) {
    $("#edit-submit")
      .attr("onClick", "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/feedback-submitted'])");
  }
});
```

This works splendidly for things such as a Submit button on a form, and I'm able to track Goals via the fake pagevisit (Events don't allow this, hence the fake trigger).

Problem is, when I've set similar onClick events to Anchor HTML elements, that take the user out of the site, I'm not seeing anything appear on our analytics, even though using same code to attach for example an alert("foo") event shows its clearly working and I get a popup.

Here is how the actual anchor element looks like after being processed with jQuery:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ad-clicked'])">Anchor text</a>
```

What am I doing wrong, since I've seen this example used on a few tutorials and the code IS executing as far as I can track it with breakpoint and alert() tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is usually always because there is not enough time for the GA code to execute before the user is taken to the next page.  This isn't a problem if the link opens a new window (target="_blank") because the original page is still there and the code can finish loading.  The common way to handle this is to use settimeout to delay the redirect a little, to give time for the GA script to execute. You can go to the link below for details on implementation.

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Comment: And on that note, you may want to consider counting outbound links as an event instead of virtual page views.

Comment: Normally I would count them via Events, but as I've understood it doesn't work for Goal tracking (and this outbound site is actually our own site, in different domain, but we want the clicks to the ad to be visible in the main site GA Goals).

Thanks for the timeout tip, got it to work!

Comment: ah yeah...forgot you mentioned goals...yeah it's pretty lame how you can't setup goals based on events.  I think I read somewhere how google has acknowledged that as a feature they will eventually add.

Comment: I think I was too soon to gloat, when testing the delay with setting the line manually:

_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", '/fakeview']);
// setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 750);

It works! But with variable:

var fakepage = "anotherfake";

setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 750);

It worked. However, when I set it to live, I've not been getting any hits afterwards.



and when calling it I use fakeView(this, 'feedbacksubmitted');

Comment: Ah it got all mixed up, doesnt work to add code in comments.

http://pastie.org/1503233

Comment: Works now, was a damn &nbsp; whitespace in the code, which wasnt visible in editor.